# Using Ionic components in innerHTML

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In Ionic 3, how can I expose the Ionic components in dynamically loaded HTML.

In the controller:
`` testHtml = `<h1>Testpage</h1><button ion-button>This should look like a button</button>`; ``

In the view/template: 
`<div innerHtml="testHtml"></div>"`

**Issue: The button is not rendered as an ion-button, but a regular html button.**

Answer (score 1):

Loading dynamic HTML will not compile the ionic components. Instead you should use the ionic classes used to create buttons like this:

```
testHtml = '<h1>Testpage</h1><button class="button button-md button-default button-default-md">This should look like a button</button>';
```

Hope this helps you.